# Jquery trying to work with dynamic id's with onclick event

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The problem I'm having is that when I click on the LIKE div it opens all textboxes

It needs to display only the one textbox on the click event.

Here is the example html:

```
<div id="sublike-1">Like</div>
<div id="sublike-form-1"><input type="text" /> Save</div>

<div id="sublike-2">Like</div>
<div id="sublike-form-2"><input type="text" /> Save</div>

<div id="sublike-3">Like</div>
<div id="sublike-form-3"><input type="text" /> Save</div>
```

My Jquery:

```
// Display Sub Like form
$(this).find("div[id^='sublike-']").live('click', function(){
 $("div").find("div[id^='sublike-form-']").toggle();
});
```

What can I do so that it does not open both textboxes at the same time, must I change my html div's, my jquery or both?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure that every textbox will be next to the "Like" element, you can use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(document).find("div[id^='sublike-']").live('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings("[id^='sublike-form-']:first").toggle();
});
```

But if textbox might be "far" from the Like element, you can parse the id:

```
$(document).find("div[id^='sublike-']").live('click', function(){
    var num = this.id.split('-')[1];
    $('#sublike-form-' + num).toggle();
});
```

Check this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/ZbTzN/

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery forum answer](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-add-event-handler-to-dynamically-created-checkbox-in-jquery)

You have to add click event to an exist element. You can not add event to dom elements dynamic created. I you want to add event to them, you should bind event to an existed element using ".on".

```
$('p').on('click','selector_you_dynamic_created',function(){...});
```

.delegate should work,too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find("div[id^='sublike-']").live('click', function(){
 $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I just changed it, this way is shorter and should still work with what you already have :)

Answer (score 0):

According to DOM, try this should work:)

```
$(this).find("div[id^='sublike-']").live('click', function(){
 $(this).next('div[id^="sublike-form-"]').toggle()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the others have posted some very working solutions based on `.live`, but I figured I'd put my solution anyway,

First, I'd suggest you change your markup a bit, if you can, like so,

```
<div class="sublike-box">
    <a class="sublike-btn">Like</a>
    <div class="sublike-form"><input type="text" /> Save</div>
</div>

<div class="sublike-box">
    <a class="sublike-btn">Like</a>
    <div class="sublike-form"><input type="text" /> Save</div>
</div>

<div class="sublike-box">
    <a class="sublike-btn">Like</a>
    <div class="sublike-form"><input type="text" /> Save</div>
</div>
```

This gives a more readable and semantic structure for the markup, making it easier to read and follow.

Next, for the code, I *strongly* encourage using [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method instead of `.live`.

```
$('div.sublike-box').delegate('a.sublike-btn', 'click', function (e) {
    $(this).next('div.sublike-form').toggle();
});
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I fix issue adding class instend of id. If you can change id into class, will work