# How can I handle events with dynamic ID in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have used dynamic id for the elements of the table. I would like to handle it in javascript. How can I do this?

```
<table>
    <%@task.each do |task|%>
        <tr id="task-<%=task.id%>">
            ....
        </tr>
</table>
```

Now in Javascript, how to get the id of the particular row to handle events like `onclick()` or `onchange()`?

Comment: Could be achieved using [`$('tr[id^="task-"]')`](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/nMhmS/1264/) but..solution provided by Rory is the way to go...

Comment: I got it.. Here is the link that helped me..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594522/jquery-trying-to-work-with-dynamic-ids-with-onclick-event

Comment: Didn't I give you the same solution ?

Comment: Yeah Thanks for that.. I made mistakes when I used it and I tried with some other. Your solution is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a incremental `id` (or any other attribute) is never a good pattern to follow; it's too rigid and eventually becomes a pain to maintain.

Instead you can achieve this by putting a common `class` on all those `tr` elements and use `this` within the event handler to refer to the element which raised the event. Here's an example:

```html
<table>
    <%@task.each do |task|%>
        <tr class="task" data-id="<%=task.id%>">
            <!- .... -->
        </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$('.task').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Comment: can I use like this: $(.addrow).data('id').after(....). It's not actually working. What is the mistake here. How to rectify?

Comment: What are you attempting to do? The code you have there would fail as `data()` doesn't return a jQuery object.

Comment: I want to insert a row after a particular row.For that I have to catch that id.

Comment: `$('.task').filter(function() { return $(this).data('id') == 'taskId'; }).after(...)`. If you need a more complete example you're best to ask a new question as that is a bit out of scope for this one.

Comment: Here is the link that helped me solve my issue..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594522/jquery-trying-to-work-with-dynamic-ids-with-onclick-event

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it using the code below

```
$(document).on('click', function (event)  or  $('tr').on('click', function (event) 
{
var id = event.target.id.toString();
alert("#"+id);
}
```

The parameter "event" holds the necessary data. check the console for the list of details present in the parameter "event".

Comment: 1) `tr` elements don't have a `val()` to set 2) Why not just use `this` instead of hacking together a selector?

Comment: Yes you can, for understanding i used the line .val("test"). the purpose of the code ends with the line var id = ..   then i used the alternate selector $(''tr") instead of $(document). After all its another possible way of achieving the same